# How to get oracle id for chainlink api call?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I need to make API call over Polygon network. I did follow the tutorials and was trying to find the Job Id and oracle Id. I was able to find the job
https://market.link/jobs/56666c3e-534d-490f-8757-521928739291. However, I cannot find the Oracle Id after clicking on Node as mentioned in the docs. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 'Job Spec' section, you can see the oracle address in the initiator part of the JSON spec. In the example above, it's 0x0a31078cd57d23bf9e8e8f1ba78356ca2090569e

Answer (score 0):

Because market.link has been decommissioned, the best way to find a Chainlink oracle is to join the Chainlink Official Discord server, and post your request into the **#operator-requests** channel.

A community node operator (such as ourselves) will respond to your request with a job id and oracle address.